# Gracefully cancel a MySQL statement in console while typing it

Tags: mysql, console

In MySQL's console, how do I gracefully cancel a MySQL statement while in the middle of typing it?

For example, let's say I type `SELECT` and then hit the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.  My console now looks like this:

```
mysql> SELECT
    ->
```

Now, if I change my mind and no longer want to complete the `SELECT` statement, how do I cancel it?

If I type <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>, then this completely exits the MySQL console, which is not what I want.

I can also type a semicolon and prematurely run the statement, but this results in a SQL syntax error.  I would prefer not to pollute MySQL's query log if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

End the statement with \c:

```
mysql> select
    -> \c
mysql>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks!  Is there any way to clear a statement while in the middle of a string variable?  For example, how would I clear out of `mysql > SELECT \`` or `mysql > SELECT '`?  Is there an easier way than typing `\`\c` or `'\c` respectively?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of